# Missing privcay settings drop down and "Add People" box with youtube private video

Tags: youtube

When editing a private video in Youtube video manager of an account connected to Google Plus I cannot find "Privacy Settings" drop down mentioned in [this](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/157177?hl=en) Google support article and there is no box below the video type to see which Plus circles or individual emails have access to the video or to add additional circles or emails.

When I just uploaded a new video after a while there was "Add People" box below the drop down where I selected Private but I can't find that for my old videos in order to add/remove circles/emails from existing videos.

What is happening there and how to add or remove circles or emails from a private video?

[image: Youtube Video Manager screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Adblock can be the problem, so if you have one try to deactive it.